# Threading in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-multithreading

I tried running the following code snippet in a Jupyter notebook:

```
    import threading
    import time         
    def worker():
        print(threading.current_thread().getName(), 'Starting')
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(threading.current_thread().getName(), 'Exiting')


    def my_service():
        print(threading.current_thread().getName(), 'Starting')
        time.sleep(0.3)
        print(threading.current_thread().getName(), 'Exiting')


    t = threading.Thread(name='my_service', target=my_service)
    w = threading.Thread(name='worker', target=worker)
    w2 = threading.Thread(target=worker)  # use default name

    w.start()
    w2.start()
    t.start()
```

This is the output:

```
    worker Starting
    Thread-10 Starting
    my_service Starting
```

I do not see the following expected outputs:

```
    Thread-10 Exiting
    worker Exiting
    my_service Exiting
```

(I do get these while running my python file using the command Line)

Is this typical in a Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 3):

You should ask for the threads to join back into the main thread of the cell before the latter stops. This can be donne by putting

```py
w.join()
w2.join()
t.join()
```

at the end of the cell.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the Python statements in the main-thread for the cell are over, Jupyter will collect the output and present that as the cell-result.

Try adding a `time.sleep(1)` at the end of your cell on Jupyter, after starting the worker-threads, and it should work.

Comment: This is a hack, and the sleep time must be tuned to the task in the thread, so `time.sleep(1)` would no longer be useful if the original threads had tasks that last longer than a second.