# How to access print output from background threads in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, multithreading, jupyter-notebook

**[Update]**
It seems this is working again as expected in JupyterLab (tested on macos and jupyterlab 3.1.13).

Some while ago, I could see the print output of a background thread in the active cell in jupyter notebook. I know this sometimes led to somewhat strange behaviour if you had an active background thread while working on in your notebook. But it came in handy for debugging.

Meanwhile, background thread printing to active cells only works while the code of the active cell is executing (see [Threading in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633435/threading-in-jupyter-notebook)).

Simple example:

```
import threading

def run():
    
    time.sleep(2)
    print('a')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('b')
    
t = threading.Thread(target=run)
t.start()

time.sleep(4)  # <-- I don't want to have this
```

What I actually want to do is to debug a pyqt5 widget, using `%gui qt5`, which means that I can't block the main thread with a sleep as I did in the example above. But then, all the prints get lost.

So my question is: Can I access the print output that happened in a background thread while no code cell has been executing?

Thanks!

Comment: Print to a file? Instead of sleeping, join the thread? I'd also question whether a Jupyter notebook is the best environment for that kind of development, I'd rather tend towards an IDE.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrich, for your comment. Maybe I should clarify: I'm looking for a close-to-no-overhead solution. Something like IPython.display.printDroppedStuff() or IPython.display.setOutputPrintsWhereverTheUserIs(True). Printing to a file and tail -f it is what I'm doing right now and it is inconvenient. joining the thread does not work because I'm blocking the main thread then.

Comment: This seems to be an issue for me in jupyter lab 2.0.2 only but not in jupyter notebook 6.1.1, it would be nice if there was an explanation why. It seems like if you launch a background thread from a cell after the cell is executed the background thread loses its stderr and stdout etc. I was thinking to perhaps solve this by using an [output widget](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Output%20Widget.html) instead and redirecting my logging to it somehow but it's too bad this is broken.